# error when building native app for android with sencha cmd

Tags: android, extjs, touch, native

I tried to build an app generated with sencha cmd,it only has the default structure,on ubuntu,but i get an error which i couldn't  find anywhere on net:

The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/wlb2/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:165: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/www/wlb2/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:158: com.sencha.exceptions.ExScript: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: failed running native packager

This is the block of code around lines 150-165:

```
  <target name="-before-page"/>
    <target name="-page">
        <property name="v2deps" value="false"/>
        <property name="args.path" location="."/>
        <property name="args.destination" location="${app.build.dir}"/>
        <property name="args.environment" value="production"/>

        <x-script-def name="x-app-build" 
                      src="${framework.config.dir}/app-build.js">
            <script src="${cmd.config.dir}/ant/JSON.js"/>
            <script src="${cmd.config.dir}/ant/ant-util.js"/>
        </x-script-def>

        <x-app-build/>

    </target>
    <target name="-after-page"/>
    <target name="page" depends="init" unless="skip.page"
            description="Builds only the application's HTML page">
        <antcall target="-before-page"/>
        <antcall target="-page"/>
        <antcall target="-after-page"/>
    </target>
```

Did anyone encountered this issue?I have installed the ruby and android sdk,i'm not sure though if android sdk is fine since i installed it as an eclipse plugin on zend studio.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue while build sencha app for production. Let me know the solution or any idea to fix the issue.   Thanks.